# How to fix Axios Network error or net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE?

Tags: reactjs

I am getting network error when i am try to access that data but Api  is display in my console but not able to access that because of network error or net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE please help me. I am fetching the data from local host In Postman everything  work fine Status is also 200ok

Code of Axios:-

```
 const [comments, setdata] = useState([]);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        getData1();
    }, [props.val, props.NextVal]);


    async function getData1() {
        console.log("Ssending Props In table", props.val, props.NextVal);
        var data = {
            CURRENTRDL: props.val,
            NEXTRDL: props.NextVal
        }
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `http://localhost:9763/api/setRundown`,
            data,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-control-allow-origin': '*'
            },
            auth: {
                username: 'admin',
                password: 'password'
            }
        }).then(response => {
            setdata([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
             console.log("table_check", [response.data]);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
        });
    }
```

[image]

This header i am sending
[image]

Comment: you can try with "await" before the response

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my backend was missing the .env file which contains environment variables.
so probably the error here is on your backend side.